# Unable to correctly spawn Raspberry Pi camera application as child process from C++ app

Tags: c++, linux, boost, child-process, boost-process

I'm coding an application on a Raspberry Pi/Raspbian in C++. I create a named pipe (FIFO) with `mkfifo()` then I start *raspiyuv* to grab image from my camera. For memory, *raspiyuv* is the Raspberry Pi command line application that takes still images and save them as YUV file.

I'm using g++ 6.3 and Boost 1.64 with *-std=c++17*. The FIFO I create is correct in the sense that I can use it from command line. It works as expected.

The bug is that the application *raspiyuv* I spawn returns immediately **with exit code 0**.

My code:

```
void myFunction()
{
    // Create the FIFO here with mkfifo(); // Works fine...
    boost::filesystem::path lExecPath = 
        boost::process::search_path( "raspiyuv" );  // returns correct path
    boost::process::child lProcess( lExecPath, "-w 2592 -h 1944 -o - -t 0 -y -s >> /var/tmp/myfifo" );
    int lPID = lProcess.id();   // Seems to be correct
    int lExitCode = lProcess.exit_code();  // Returns immediately with 0
}
```

The command `$ raspiyuv -w 2592 -h 1944 -o - -t 0 -y -s` is correct when I enter it directly to the command line. Also, the redirection to the FIFO works correctly. `-w 2592 -h 1944` give the size of the grabbed image, `-o -` means output image to stdout, `-t 0` means wait forever, `-y` means save only the Y channel and `-s` means wait for SIGUSR1 to trigger image capture.

When I call it from the command line, the application is idle until I send a SIGUSR1 then it captures an image and streams it to the FIFO then returns idle. That's fine.

When I spawn it by creating the `boost::process::child` object, it returns immediately.

Any idea to correct this and allow the `boost::process::child` to remain alive as long as my application (parent process) is alive and I don't send a SIGKILL, etc.?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The `boost::process::child`runs asyncronously to main process. If you want synchronous behavior then you must either call `lProcess.wait()`
or launch that raspiyuv by synchronous means like using `boost::process::system`.

**EDIT:**
If you want the other process to be asynchronous (as your edits and comment seem to indicate) then what you really try to do becomes unclear to me:

> The bug is that the application raspiyuv I spawn returns immediately
>   with **exit code 0**.

What bug? By [docs of `boost::process::child`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idp31591104-bb) it is **exactly** what is expected:

> 5. int exit_code() const; 
>      Get the exit_code. The return value is without
>      any meaning if the child wasn't waited for or if it was terminated.

Your code nowhere waits for child to end and so gets exit code like documented.

Comment: Actually, I do want it to run _asynchronously_. I will sporadically synchronize it by sending a __SIGUSR1__ signal to the child process. What I want is a child process that runs asynchronously like a thread (but being a different process). Any way... I'll try `boost::process::system` when I will have access to my computer.

Comment: I extended my answer since I really do not understand what is the issue  if you expected the child process to be asynchronous.

Comment: The problem is that launching `raspiyuv ... -t 0 -s ...` should start the app in a (forever) idle state waiting for SIGUSR1 to trig actual image capture _then go back to idle state waiting for next SIGUSR1_. It should not return immediately with code 0.

Comment: No, the problem is that your posted code does not wait for what you attempt to execute to complete so it can't detect what the exit code of it is.

Comment: No the program returns immediatelly. When I run it with the debugger, it even returns and its PID disappears when I do `ps aux`. It should not.

Comment: I did nowhere write how soon it returns. I wrote that your code does not wait for exit code.